# How to properly pass an array from a select form to another PHP page

Tags: php, html, forms

Let me explain further.  I have a select form on my first php page (lets call this page first.php). I do have a submit button. I am catching the array on the second page (lets cal this page sec.php) with $_POST and then setting it to a PHP variable. However, I can not get it to print. Here's what my code/mark up looks like on first.php

```
<label>Product:</label>
    <select name="arr[]">
        <option value="Mobile">Mobile</option>
        <option value="Social">Social</option>
        <option value="Online">Online</option>
    </select>
```

Note = I know I don't need to have an array for this. But I want to keep it this way.

Here's what my code looks like on sec.php:

```
<?php
    $arr= $_POST['arr'];
?>
```

I want it to print in this HTML table:

```
<tr>
    <td width="200"> <?php echo $url[0]; ?></td>
    <td width="200"> <?php echo $sMonth[0] . "/" . $sDay[0] . "/" . $sYear[0]; ?></td>
    <td width="200"> <?php echo $eMonth[0] . "/" . $eDay[0] . "/" . $eYear[0]; ?></td>
    <td> <?php echo $tBudget[0]; ?></td>
    <td> <?php echo $dBudget[0]; ?></td>
    <td> <?php echo $model[0]; ?></td>
    <td> <?php echo $bid[0]; ?></td>
    <td> <?php echo $target[0]; ?></td>
    <td> <?php echo $status[0]; ?></td>
    <td width="200"> <?php echo $arr[0]; ?></td>
    <td> <?php echo $tUnits[0]; ?></td>
</tr>
```

NOTE = all other variables and values print just FINE (by using the same method and concept as the $arr variable) But ONLY the $arr variable is unable to print).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `var_dump($arr);` show?  How about `var_dump($_POST);`?

Comment: var_dump($arr) says this: dasarray(1) { [0]=> string(6) "Mobile" }

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
<select name="arr[]">
...
<td width="200"> <?php echo $arr[0]; ?></td>
```

to

```
<select name="arr">
...
<td width="200"> <?php echo $arr; ?></td>
```

You'll **only** want to use `array naming` when you have a **multiple** select option

Comment: Can you elaborate on that further? it's not multiple. User selects ONE option, that option will be put into the array.

Comment: @user3108505 exactly, since you only passing ONE value, you don't need to name your select `arr[]` and you only read it in your php like this: `$arr` instead of `arr[0]` since it's not an array. Read my updated answer.

Comment: My other variables are implemented the same way using the same concept and implementation. They all print except for arr

Comment: @user3108505 is your select into the `<form>` tags of your form?

Comment: Yes it is. So is my other select tags that I have used for my other variables/arrays.

Comment: @user3108505 if `var_dump($arr)` is showing this: `array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "Mobile" }` like you wrote above, then it should be working...

Comment: I know. Like I said, my other variables, same concept, same implementation, they print. Except for $arr. It's driving me crazy.

Comment: @user3108505 does `var_dump($_POST);` shows all your fields? is `$tUnits[0];` displaying anything?

Comment: Yes, all my variables print fine as accordingly. Except for $arr

Comment: @user3108505 did you resolve the issue? I'm guessing something in your 'sec.php' should be wrong (probably before assigning the variable `$arr` )...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's probably something like that:

```
   <select name="arr[]" multiple>
      <option value="Mobile">Mobile</option>
      <option value="Social">Social</option>
      <option value="Online">Online</option>
   </select>
```

Comment: but having "multiple" would cause all 3 values to be inserted. I don't want that. I want the selected option to be inserted into the first elemental position only.

Answer (score 0):

u need to use for loop to get values in your array check this

```html
<form action="<?php echo @$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="POST"> 
            <select name="arr[]" multiple>
                <option>Radio</option>
                <option>TV</option>
                <option>Keyboard</option>
                <option>DVD Player</option>
                <option>Screen</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="GO!">
        </form>
<?php
$data=@$_POST['arr'];
$len = count($data); // getting length of ur array that u need to condition ur loop
for($y=0;$y<$len;$y++){
    echo "$data[$y]"."<br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: if u wont use loop don't use multiple then , multiple let user choose many value that's why you make select arr[] as (array) , best way to print array values = looping , in you'r code you just print the first index of arr[0] lemme know why ?!!